# 1 files were skipped because there was no net space savings

Tags: android, image, android-image, webp

I am trying to convert a PNG image file into a webP image file. but it gives me an error even my application minSdkVersion>19 but i don't know why its give me an error like this

```
0 files were converted 

1 files were skipped because there was no net space savings
```

Answer (score 8):

Skipped because converted image larger than original. If you want to convert image anyway then disable `Skip files where the encoded result is larger than the original` in the settings.
[Options dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Rdz.png)

Comment: Including the screenshot isn't necessary. Just type the name here and where you can find the setting.

Comment: No, it's not converting into larger but is converting into smaller as compared to the original one.

Comment: And what settings are you talking about can you pls explain it in more details.

Comment: When you right click on the image, click on the `Convert to WebP`. 
In settings window you can disable this option.

Comment: @MayurPatel I have attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with something different...

In the "Converting images to WEBP" Dialog, select the option "Use lossless encoding", with just that option, android studio converts the image.

[image: image to web conversion dialog with loseless encoding]

--

I think studio should check the Lossy encoding issue in this topic :S