# Android Studio IDE Convert Images to WebP does not convert

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, webp

I am using `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1` after generating the `ic_launcher` icon for my app I get all the icons in `mipmap` resource folder as `.png` images. The default icons were in `.webp` format so I want to convert the automatically generated `.png` icons in `.webp`.

However, following the official guide on [converting images to WebP](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp#convert_images_to_webp) in Android Studio nothing happens no matter the options I select (e.g. even if I uncheck `Skip files where the encoded result is larger than the original`). My `minSdkVersion` is 23 so it's not due to the transparency not being supported before api level 18.

I only get a generic message saying that the conversion was skipped but I don't understand why...
[image]

Am I missing something? Is this a bug in the latest IDE version?

Comment: Same here... the error text i've found in the folowwing: 
"1 file was skipped because there was no net space saving"

Comment: Retaled question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720370/1-files-were-skipped-because-there-was-no-net-space-savings/71878696#71878696

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the launcher icon in `webp` format was not supported but now that is not the case. I think that's why Android studio doesn't convert those launcher icons to `webp` format.

Fix: If you can rename those files using file explorer in Windows or Finder in Mac then Android studio will not consider those as launcher icons(as renamed is not performed in Android studio, it will not be able to track it). After that tool will work perfectly.

See the `If the minSdkVersion of a new project is set to API 18 or higher, the launcher icons created in newly created projects will be .webp images instead of .png.`  in the [android doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/webp) for `webp` support for launcher icon after API 18